# RFID and fingerprint scanner in one python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I wrote two separate scripts for the RFID and fingerprint scanner which check for ID and data on the tag or a positive answer from the fingerprint scannner and execute a ssh command. I would like to merge them into one script with the script detecting wether a RFID tag or a finger is presented.

I thought about using the inductive trigger on the fingerprint scanner but this won’t work as it checks the state at the beginning of the loop and then waits for a tag to be presented.

The RFID is a run-of-the-mill MFRC522.
Fingerprint sensor:
https://www.adafruit.com/product/4651

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

finger.py

```
import time
import board
import adafruit_fingerprint
import serial
import subprocess

uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=57600, timeout=1)
finger = adafruit_fingerprint.Adafruit_Fingerprint(uart)



def get_fingerprint():
    while finger.get_image() != adafruit_fingerprint.OK:
        pass
    if finger.image_2_tz(1) != adafruit_fingerprint.OK:
        return False
    if finger.finger_search() != adafruit_fingerprint.OK:
        return False
    return True


try:
    finger.set_led(1,4,0,0)
    while True:
        finger.set_led(1,4,0,0)
        if get_fingerprint():
            finger.set_led(2,1,200,0)
            subprocess.call('ssh pi@192.168.2.3 sudo python3 /home/pi/pirfid/actor.py',shell=True)
            
        else:
            finger.set_led(1,2,10,5)
            time.sleep(1)
            finger.set_led(1,2,10,5)
            time.sleep(1)
            finger.set_led(1,2,10,5)
            time.sleep(1)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Aborted by User")
    uart.close()
finally:
    uart.close()
```

rfid.py

```
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import os
import secrets

#Create object for RFID module
scan = SimpleMFRC522()

#Master Tag present
def masterPresent(file_pathUID,id,file_pathPIN,pin):
        with open(file_pathUID, 'r') as fileUID:
                content = fileUID.readline()
                if str(id) in content:
                        masterID = 1
                else:
                        masterID = 0
        with open(file_pathPIN, 'r') as filePIN:
                content = filePIN.readline()
                pin = pin.strip()
                content = content.strip()
                if pin in content:
                        masterPIN = 1
                else:
                        masterPIN = 0
        if masterID == 1 and masterPIN == 1:
                tagAuth("/home/pi/pi-rfid/known_UID","/home/pi/pi-rfid/known_PIN")
        else:
                pass

#Authorise new Tag
def tagAuth(file_pathUID,file_pathPIN):
        # Read Tag UID and write to file
        print("----------------")
        print("Master Tag detected")
        print("----------------")
        sleep(2)
        print("Place Tag to authorise")
        id,data = scan.read()
        id = str(id)
        pin = data.strip()
        with open(file_pathUID, 'r') as fileUID:
                contentID = fileUID.read()
        with open(file_pathPIN, 'r') as filePIN:
                contentPIN = filePIN.read()
                if id in contentID or pin in contentPIN:
                        print("----------------")
                        print("Tag already in use")
                        print("----------------")
                        sleep(3)

                else:
                        with open (file_pathUID,'a+') as fileUID:
                                fileUID.write("\n")
                                fileUID.write(id)
                                #Create random hex sring and write to tag and file
                                newPIN = secrets.token_hex(16)
                                scan.write(newPIN)
                                with open (file_pathPIN,'a+') as filePIN:
                                        filePIN.write("\n")
                                        filePIN.write(newPIN)
                                print("----------------")
                                print("New Tag sucessfully authorised")
                                print("----------------")
                                sleep (3)

#Search UID in file
def searchUID(file_pathUID,id):
        global idInList
        with open(file_pathUID, 'r') as fileUID:
                content = fileUID.read()
                if id in content:
                        idInList = 1
                else:
                        idInList = 0

#Search PIN in file
def searchPIN(file_pathPIN,pin):
        global pinInList
        with open(file_pathPIN, 'r') as filePIN:
                content = filePIN.read()
                pin = pin.strip()
                if pin in content:
                        pinInList = 1
                else:
                        pinInList = 0

#Unlock over SSH
def unlockSSH():
        subprocess.call('ssh pi@192.168.2.3 sudo python3 /home/pi/pirfid/actor.py',shell=True)

#Check for Access
def checkAccess():
        global pinMatch,idInLiist
        if idInList == 1 and pinInList == 1:
                print("Access granted")
                print("----------------")
                unlockSSH()
        else:
                print("Access denied")
                print("----------------")

#Loop

try:
        while True:
                print("Place your Tag")
                id,data = scan.read()
                printData()
                masterPresent("/home/pi/pi-rfid/known_UID",id,"/home/pi/pi-rfid/known_PIN",data)
                searchUID("/home/pi/pi-rfid/known_UID",str(id))
                searchPIN("/home/pi/pi-rfid/known_PIN",data)
                checkAccess()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Aborted by User")
        GPIO.cleanup()
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use threads to run both tasks in parallel. Something like this for example:

```py
def rfid_task():
    # run RFID loop here
    try:
        while True:
            ...

def finger_task():
    # run fingerprint loop here
    try:
        finger.set_led(1,4,0,0)
        while True:
            ...

# this is the main entry point
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create a threads that will run both loops in parallel
    rfid_thread = threading.Thread(target=rfid_task)
    finger_thread = threading.Thread(target=finger_task)

    # wait until both threads finish
    rfid_thread.join()
    finger_thread.join()
```

I don't see any problems with your code, but keep in mind that threading can introduce race conditions (because different parts of your code can run at the same time). It could indeed cause problems with the hardware libraries, maybe it is neccessary to allocate the resources from within the threads.

Also I would consider re-starting the loops on failure (e.g. by wrapping them in another `while True:`, probably with some timeout). Otherwise I would implement some kind of mechanism that stop the remaining thread if the other one fails.

Comment: Would problems occur if only one of the threads is called upon at a time?

Comment: Did some research and it seems race conditions come up specifically when using shared variables within both threads, which isn’t the case in my scripts. So far everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are indeed correct. I am not sure about hardware libraries though, it might be better to initialize the `uart`, `finger` and `scan` variables inside the thread functions. However, if you did not experience any problems so far, I would not worry too much about it.